# remove from end of the string and add new char to he beginning?

Tags: python

I want to convert `"23!-32/2!*3!-20"` to `"factorial(23)-32/factorial(2)*factorial(3)-20"`

I could do this much:

```
import re
from math import factorial
operators = "\+\-\*\/"
exp = "23!-32/2!\*3!-20"

def splitter(stri):
    list1 = []
    for i in stri:
        list1.append(i)
    return list1

list2 = []
for i in re.findall("[\w\+\-\*\/][0-9]+?[!]",exp):
    i = re.sub("!", "",i)
    if i[0] in operators:
        i = splitter(i)
        i.insert(1,"factorial(")
        i.append(")")
        i = "".join(i)
    else:
        i = "factorial(" + i + ")"
    list2.append(i)

exp = "".join(list2)
print(exp)
```

the code does "seems" to work but then it only returns factorial(23)-32/factorial(2)*factorial(3) and eats away "-20" and "-32" from the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue:

```
import re

data = "23!-32/2!*3!-20"

result = re.sub(r'(\d+)!', r"factorial(\1)", data)
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
factorial(23)-32/factorial(2)*factorial(3)-20
```

Comment: Sounds a bit odd, since they're already using regular expressions...

Comment: @superbrain: The title "(Better use of) regular expressions" would be a bit offending, wouldn't it? Also the used expression was a bit odd.

Comment: well i am new to regexp, any helpful guied that can help me, would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see how that would be offending. If anything, I'd say the current way is offending. As far as I know, it's like [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/188245) puts it, that "X to the rescue" is a phrase commonly used to imply that X is going to arrive on the scene and rectify the situation in some way. But regular expressions can't arrive on the scene when they're already there. You make it sound like the OP didn't think of regular epressions, when in reality they did.